# Python: Write a list of tuples to a file

Tags: python

How can I write the following list:

```
[(8, 'rfa'), (8, 'acc-raid'), (7, 'rapidbase'), (7, 'rcts'), (7, 'tve-announce'), (5, 'mysql-im'), (5, 'telnetcpcd'), (5, 'etftp'), (5, 'http-alt')]
```

to a text file with two columns `(8 rfa)` and many rows, so that I have something like this:

```
8 rfa
8 acc-raid
7 rapidbase
7 rcts
7 tve-announce
5 mysql-im
5 telnetcpcd
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
with open('daemons.txt', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write('\n'.join('%s %s' % x for x in mylist))
```

If you want to use str.format(), replace 2nd line with:

```
    fp.write('\n'.join('{} {}'.format(x[0],x[1]) for x in mylist))
```

Comment: `str.format` is the new idiom for formatting strings: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/. Although I'm sure `%` will last for many many moons... =)

Comment: That should be `fp.write('\n'.join('{} {}'.format(x[0],x[1]) for x in mylist)` and `fp` is a file object (opened for writing, I assume). Format does not seem to take a tuple as an argument or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @sup: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Ah, I always wondered what that asterisk meant. So it is `fp.write('\n'.join('{} {}'.format(*x) for x in mylist)`

Comment: looks like the str.format line is missing the last parentheses, should be `fp.write('\n'.join('{} {}'.format(x[0],x[1]) for x in mylist))`

Answer (score 21):

```
import csv
with open(<path-to-file>, "w") as the_file:
    csv.register_dialect("custom", delimiter=" ", skipinitialspace=True)
    writer = csv.writer(the_file, dialect="custom")
    for tup in tuples:
        writer.write(tup)
```

The [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params) module is very powerful!

Comment: +1 as useful for creating csv, but should this not be `writer.writerow(tup)`?

Answer (score 5):

```
open('filename', 'w').write('\n'.join('%s %s' % x for x in mylist))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the third way that I came up with:

```
for number, letter in myList:
    of.write("\n".join(["%s %s" % (number, letter)]) + "\n")
```

Comment: you don't need to turn it into a list to pass to `join`. other then that, it's almost exactly like Ignacio's answer, so you should probably accept his by clicking the checkmark under the votecount next to his answer..

Answer (score 2):

simply convert the tuple to string with `str()`

```
f=open("filename.txt","w+")
# in between code
f.write(str(tuple)+'/n')
# continue
```

Answer (score 1):

For flexibility, for example; if some items in your list contain 3 items, others contain 4 items and others contain 2 items you can do this.

```
mylst = [(8, 'rfa'), (8, 'acc-raid','thrd-item'), (7, 'rapidbase','thrd-item','fourth-item'),(9, 'tryrt')]

# this function converts the integers to strings with a space at the end
def arrtostr(item):
    strr=''
    for b in item:
        strr+=str(b)+'   '
    return strr

# now write to your file
with open('list.txt','w+') as doc:
    for line in mylst:
        doc.write(arrtostr(line)+'\n')
    doc.close()
```

And the output in list.txt

```
8   rfa   
8   acc-raid   thrd-item   
7   rapidbase   thrd-item   fourth-item   
9   tryrt
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding f-strings in Python you can use this example:

```
mylst = [(8, 'rfa'), (8, 'acc-raid'), (7, 'rapidbase'), (7, 'rcts'), (7, 'tve-announce'), (5, 'mysql-im')]
f = open('out.txt', mode='w+')
for elem in mylst:
    f.write(f'{elem}\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

why not simply use a for loop and a f string?

```
my_list_of_tuples = [(8, 'rfa'), (8, 'acc-raid'), (7, 'rapidbase'), (7, 'rcts'), (7, 'tve-announce'), (5, 'mysql-im'), (5, 'telnetcpcd'), (5, 'etftp'), (5, 'http-alt')]
with open("myfile.txt", mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for tup in my_list_of_tuples:
        file.write(f"{tup[0]} {tup[1]}\n")
```