# Python - writing a list of tuples to a file turns out shifted

Tags: python, list, tuples

I've seen answers to this questions in SO, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366276/writing-a-list-of-tuples-to-a-text-file-in-python), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820312/python-write-a-list-of-tuples-to-a-file). However, using the methods they suggested, the output I get in the file looks partly shifted.

Specifically, I've got a list of tuples, consisting of a number and a string. Using this solution, for example:

```
for t in sorted_words:
      wrds.write(''.join(str(s) for s in t) + ' ')
```

What I get in the file is of the following format:

```
wordone
0.0 wordtwo
0.0 wordthree
0.0 wordfour
0.0
```

Any explanation for this? Thank you!

Comment: Can you expand the source code, show the tuple `sorted_words` at least?

Comment: Thanks @Paulo, for the edit (I forgot how to style codes here...). You're right to ask for `sorted_words`, that's where my error was, as user2357112 pointed out. Thanks so much anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your word strings have newlines at the end of them.

If you want output in the following form:

```
wordone 0.0
wordtwo 0.0
wordthree 0.0
```

you should take the newlines off, then use

```
for word, weight_or_whatever in sorted_words:
    wrds.write("{} {}\n".format(word, weight_or_whatever))
```

(I'm not sure what the numbers represent.)

Comment: Thanks so much @user2357112! You're absolutely right... sorry about the stupid mistake (I'm using encoded strings and they're so long I didn't really notice the \n...excuses ;-) ).

Answer (score 2):

As user2357112 pointed out, your strings have newlines at the end, so you can use [strip()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) which removes leading and trailing whitespace, including newlines.

```
for t in sorted_words:
      wrds.write(' '.join(str(s).strip() for s in t) + '\n')
```